# change url content to another controller in yii

Tags: yii

In my view->category->index.php, I show category names from category table. Then
by $_get['id'] of cat_id, I show product names for a particular category id.

Here's the code:

```
$por=product::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('cat_id'=>$_GET['cat_id']));
$list = CHtml::listData($por,'pd_id','product_name');
foreach($list as $value)
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($value),
                 array('showproduct',
                'id'=>$data->pd_id));
```

For example, if we have in the `category` table:

```
cat_id = 1, cat_name = "nokia"
```

and in the `product` table:

```
product_id = 1, cat_id = 1, product_name = "N72"
product_id = 2, cat_id = 1, product_name = "N73"
```

Then I can dynamically show the two product names.

my doubt is,how to show features(from feature table,
feature table has category and product id as foreign keys) of N72,by clicking N72.
and how to apply chtml link and write action to perform this in same view->category->index.php.

please advice !

Answer (score 0):

Create new relation in Product model:

```php
public function relations() {
    ...
    'features' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Features', 'product_id')
}
```

Now you can use $por->features to get all features of the product, but you have to change your code from procedural/arrays to more oop.

```php
$products = Product::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('cat_id'=>$_GET['cat_id']));
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($product->product_name),
                 array('showproduct',
                'id'=>$product->pd_id));
    foreach ($product->features as $feature)
        echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($feature->feature_name),
                 array('features/showfeature',
                'id'=>$feature->ft_id))."\n";
}
```

Here i don't know you Features table structure, so i've put similar to Products column names. Also i don't know what other controller you want the link to point, so i've put 'features/showfeature' which is FeatureController and actionShowFeature as action.

Comment: john,u r correct!!..relations between the category,product and feature table are generated by yii framework,after creating and set foreign keys.In view of mobile site,if i click product name,it should display corresponding feature of that product name.Am asking what is code inside chtml::link($value); , do u understand yaar ??

Comment: @jayaraj If you click product name your browser sends you to other action. in that action you have to render a view where you can show all features of selected product. You don't have to change CHtml::link in that case.  You can't get features after conversion of model collection ($por) into array ($list). If you still want to get features you have to use code style i showed above.

Comment: ok.i understood.i shall concentrate on that action to render a view.thanks yaar !!!..support till earth exists.